# Remove inline styles from Create React App

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I am working on a React application which is built using [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app). I am having some trouble with CSS in my application. The CSS in `dev` mode is not consistent with CSS in `production` mode. Some CSS is inline in `dev` mode, under multiple `<style>` tags under `<head>`. But the same CSS is in a separate file in `prod` mode. This is causing some unexpected over-rides, which in turn is causing some CSS issues in production. Is there a way to completely remove all inline CSS from both `dev` and `prod` so that the behaviour is consistent everywhere?

I believe the issue is with how `webpack` is bundling the application in these modes.

Note: I don't want to `eject` my `create-react-app`.

Comment: you can just copy and paste it?

Comment: Copy and paste what?

Comment: the css from inline into a file

Comment: so there are elements which are styled like this style="somestyle" and thats what you want to remove? Just do a regex search and replace?

Comment: All css in my app is in files. But when it lands on the browser in dev mode, some of that css is inlined.